Run a script before Installation of VSTO add-in
I want to run a very short set of lines in command prompt before the VSTO Add-In gets installed.
Ideally, users would click on setup.exe, then

my custom lines get executed
Add-In installs.

I want to do similar after the add-in is uninstalled.
Is there a good tutorial on how to do this? I tried several approaches but it never seems to really work in the end...
Workaround
I have a workaround which I really don't like. It's basically another project, where the executable runs the two lines of code before running another executable.
It works, but it doesn't feel right.

Whats the problem in creating an installer that does this?

My workaround feels redundant. Also installs two "programs" to windows, both visible in "Add or Remove Programs". Like I said, it works, but it doesn't feel like the right way to do this.

Why 2 programs? Just write an installer that executes those ominous 2 lines and registers(and in the case of uninstal unregisters) the Add-In? Where does 2 programs come from?

@Ralf Yeah that's exactly the question. For my VSTO AddIn I am using the default installer that comes with the clickonce.
Now the I tried to write a custom installer (or something, I don't know how to call it), that executes those omnious 2 lines and then registers the Add-in.
But I couldn't find a tutorial or something. Would you happen to know how to do it?

There are a gazillion ways of creating a installer. This is one from Microsoft for VSTO add-ins itself.

I tried following this, step by step. But somehow this does not install my VSTO. The installation wizzard opens, i can navigate through the process untill sucessful status. But The AddIn is not installed. What I do get is a new folder in Program Files (x86).
Soo... Yeah, doesn't really work as I would have imagined.
